# Pass Parameters To Base Webpack config

Tags: typescript, webpack

we are trying to get webpack set up with a base and multiple entry configs.  With the base doing almost everything but a few extra files included depending on the build destination.  We have the entry for the base set up as follows:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = (env) => {
    return {
        entry: {
            ...
        },
        output: {
            ...
        },
        optimization: {
            ...
        },
        module: {
            ...
        },
        resolve: {
            ...
        },
        plugins: [
            ...
        ]
    };
};
```

And the entry configs set up as follows:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env) => {    
    return merge(common(env), {
        mode: 'production',
        plugins: [
            ...
        ]
    });
}
```

This is working fine on my machine but when someone else runs it they get:

> TypeError: common is not a function

Is this the best way to pass options into the entry and base webpack files?  It all seems to work fine locally and builds everything correctly and it runs.  We use webpack.DefinePlugin to make then entries passed in available in the javascript application.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `webpack.common.js`?

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks for responding, the typescript error is happening at line 7, position 18 which is the line: return merge(common(env), {.  The start of the common(env) so it's never getting into webpack.common.js.  Is this the right way with webpack to pass an env object down or is there a better way that would potentially work on the machine this is not working on?

Comment: Hi there. `common is not a function` means `require('./webpack.common.js')` didn't return a function when line 1 was processed. The reason I asked for the contents of it was to understand why `./webpack.common.js` did not export a `common` function. This seems like it should work, but if you're using task runners, you might be able to use command-line arguments, e.g. using [`yargs`](https://github.com/yargs/yargs)

Comment: Hi Mehmet, apologies I understand what you are saying, I have included the entire file with the minutiae removed.  Hopefully this isn't too far off where it should be.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to create [this minimal app](https://github.com/seckin92/webpack-param-repro) to reproduce this, but everything seems to be working fine. Can you and the other people who get this error run this minimal app without problems? Do you and the other people who get the error have the same versions of `node`,  `npm`, `webpack` etc. installed? The error looks like it's related to `node` rather than `webpack` itself.

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks for your help with this.  In the end it was an issue on that machine with the merge after I got hold of their local copy.  Thanks again for your time though.

Comment: No problem, glad it was resolved!

Answer (score 4):

Just posting the minimal repro set-up for future reference (which worked fine for me) as I deleted the repository. The problem was a merge issue, not related to webpack.

```
// file: src/hello-world.js
module.exports = () => {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
}

// file: src/index.js
const helloWorld = require('./hello-world');
helloWorld();

// file: webpack.common.js
module.exports = (env) => {
    console.log("./webpack.common: " + env + " was passed for argument 'env'.");
    return {
        mode: env
    }    
};

// file: webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = (env) => {
    return merge(common(env), {});
};

// file: package.json
{
  "name": "webpack-param-repro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal app to reproduce the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/q/52594681/824495",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mehmet Seckin",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/seckin92/webpack-param-repro"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a good alternative solution [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge). Do not reinvent the wheel. It's already exists :)

Comment: I believe the OP is already using `webpack-merge`, please re-check the entry config provided in the original question.